# Words deleted in front of backspace with vim in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscodevim

I've run into a little annoying issue (feature?) with VSCode. The problem is when I hold down backspace when editing my .tex file in vim occasionally characters get deleted in front of the cursor. I've included a GIF below to highlight the issue:

[image: gif showing the bug]

The word "plutonium" is gone at the end. I was just holding backspace...

EDIT: Work around found by switching VSCode Vim emulator from V1.26.0 -> V1.25.2. Seems like V1.26.0 has lots of bugs... Still not fixed in V1.26.0 at time of writing. Follow issue ticket [here](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/issues/8641)

Comment: Maybe its me, but I don't see anything abnormal in the  gif.  By "space bar", I assume you mean the text cursor.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "cursor" more coffee needed :D. The GIF isn't very good. Let me make another one where it's more clear. The point is that I'm holding backspace and the word "Ut" gets deleted in front of the cursor... This doesn't happen with any other editor I've ever used.

Comment: Oh - now that you pointed it out.  That's interesting...  I see it now! Also, "just holding space bar" - I think you meant backspace now...

Comment: Edit: Changed GIF. The word "plutonium" is deleted.

Comment: Perhaps worth entering an issue on their github: https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/issues

Comment: RE spacebar: *smh* I really need more coffee.

Comment: if you raise an issue ticket, please add a link here to your issue ticket so I can follow it.

Comment: Ticket here: https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/issues/8641

Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Work around found by switching VSCode Vim emulator from V1.26.0 -> V1.25.0